# When Turing Machine looped?

Tags: turing-machines

Turing Machine stay at first cell and dont move to the left/right. Its condition!!!(Machine can only rewrite content of cell or dont do anything)

Turing Machine looped when two iterations in which the content of the cell is same, the state of machine is the same, and therefore these are completely identical(*).

And I need to know when this Turing Machine looped. How many iteration will be between (*)?

Comment: Is it (lenght of alphabet)*(number of states)?

Comment: Please don't re-post your question.  Instead, edit your original question to address the feedback there.  Don't guess about the answer -- try to prove it correct, spend some more time on this, and then if you get stuck, you will be able to edit to show your progress and ask a more specific question about your approach.  I encourage you to read the link I shared with you there and use that to improve your question.

Comment: @D.W. I edit my old question(you ignore me) then i post new one. And you ban it. What's wrong my new question?